# Statistical test with unequal sample sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

If I have two samples with vastly different sample sizes (say n1 = 800 and n2 = 21,000) what statistical test would give me the most reliable results? I've been using the Mann Witney U test. Is the t-test better? I'm more concerned about the statistical power because I know that as my groups become more unequal, the less reliable my results will be. What statistical test will allow me to optimize my statistical power?

Comment: Having sample sizes of 800 and 21,000 is far better than 800 and 800.  Having unequal sample sizes isn't a bad thing.  Having more samples is a good thing.

Comment: @JimBaldwin What if my n2 = 100,000 and my n1 = 800? Would that still be better than the two sample sizes being less and closer to equal?

Comment: Even better.  The variance of the sample difference will be even smaller.  Don't know where this "we must have equal sample sizes" came from.

Comment: @Jim Actually, having sample sizes of 800 and 21,000 isn't a whole lot better than 800 and 800.  In the limit as 21,000 becomes very large, the variance of a typical statistic (such as Student's t) is only halved. There's practically no difference in power between (800,21000) and (800,100000). It's really the smaller of the two sample sizes that drives the power.

Comment: @whuber.  No disagreement.  If one is designing a study, then such lopsided differences in sample sizes usually don't make much sense.  However, some folks seem to think that once one has the two disparate sample sizes, then they might have to get rid of some of the data.  That's where I say there's nothing that needs fixing.

Comment: @Jim That's a good point and worth focusing on. It addresses the misconception that "more imbalanced" equals "less reliable."

Comment: @Jim Thank you guys for clarifying. I was reading about power and I must have gotten some false information. Thanks again